# Classifying space for singular foliations

Tags: differential-topology, classifying-spaces

I apologize if this question is not appropriate for this site. I am aware of the n'th Haefliger groupoid, which acts as a classifying space for codimension-n foliations. Is there something similar for singular foliations, with varying codimension? Furthermore, does this object admit a nice construction in terms of the Haefliger groupoids?

Comment: In a now-deleted answer, Gael Meigniez asks: "Are your foliations Riemannian?"

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that; they are not Riemannian foliations.